# Ошибка. Проблема в коде или в среде?

Tags: c++

Ошибка: main.cpp|10|error: expected ')' before 'st'

Строка в которой ошибка:

`if(st[j]!=' ' && (st[j+1]==' ' || st[j+1]=='\0' || st[j+1]=='.' || st[j+1]=='!' st[j+1]=='?'))`

Comment: После `st[j+1]=='!'` ошибка. Добавьте `||`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Грамматика нарушена - не хватает || в предпоследней дизъюнкции

Answer (score 1):

После `st[j+1]=='!'` вы забыли `||`
Будьте внимательнее